# Importing a multi-column Excel sheet and creating a "lookup" style search

Tags: excel, matlab, interpolation

I have bunch of Excel files, where every file is with multiple columns, of which I need for the post-processing five. There are several difficulties I've encountered in importing them into Matlab.

The data is as follows in columns but here with descriptive numbers:

```
text1   0   0   -10   20 
text1   0   0   -11   19 
text1   0   0   -12   18 
text1   0   0   -13   17
...
```

---

The first three columns are parameters, two last cols are results. The 4th column values are always negative and (monot. but step size varies) decreasing. The 5th column values are positive and (monot. but step size varies) decreasing. Further extraction for the clarification below.

---

```
text1   0   1   -10   20
text1   0   1   -11   19
... 
text2   10  5   -10   20
text2   10  5   -11   19 
....
```

Now I search for every parameter combination (the three first columns) a threshold value, say 15.5, from the last column. The task is to return the value from the 4th column from the same row. This is repeated for every parameter combination.

So far I imported separately the text column because it appeared as NaN if done together with the other columns. When searching for the threshold value there is no exact match; as such it is not a problem but it would be nice to interpolate the 4th column result based on the distances (5th col's n_th value - threshold) and (threshold - 5th col's (n+1)_th value). That is, as an example, if the two subsequent 5th column's values around the threshold (now 15.5) are 14 and 16, I should respectively interpolate on the 4th column's values (that could be on those rows e.g. -17 and -17.5 leading to interpolated result -17.375).

---

Case is more or less solved, here the main parts of the solution:

Import: because of varying number of rows in the data the import is done twice.

```
    [~, ~, raw] = xlsread(strcat(path,filename,'.xlsx'),sheet);
    [nRows, nCols] = size(raw); % All read in, what is the size?
    rangetext = strcat('B2:B',num2str(nRows)); % text imported separately
    [~,~, raw] = xlsread(strcat(path,filename,'.xlsx'),sheet,rangetext);
```

Similarly the numeric cells but into a different variable ('RawData'). Change strings to numerical values in a for-loop (variable 'orient').

Next search for the parameter combination and interpolate. The Vals-parameters contain all the possible values of the parameters

```
for k=1:length(oriVals)
  for kk=1:length(thetaVals)
      for kkk = 1:length(phiVals)
          % Find measurement values from the data table
          ind = find((orient==oriVals(k)).*(RawData(:,1)==thetaVals(kk)).*(RawData(:,2)==
          phiVals(kkk)));
          if ~isempty(ind)
              %% Perform interpolation 
              [tmp_tput,uniInd] = unique(RawData(ind,4));   % Remove redundant values
              tmp_dB = RawData(ind(uniInd),3);
              [~,sortInd] = sort(tmp_tput);           % Sort to ascending order for interp1

              resMat(k,kk,kkk) = interp1(tmp_tput(sortInd),tmp_dB(sortInd),lookup);   
              % Interpolate, lookup is the look up value 
          end
      end
    end
 end
```

Comment: Post some code? At least the code you used to import. Also check out the third output of `xlsread` which will have both the text and the numbers together...

Comment: Added the importing code that was mainly generated automatically Matlab. The third output may resolve the case for the data formatting but I need to look at it more closely. Remains the "lookup" part with possible interpolation.

Comment: Added the solution, pls, see above